# Find y position and width of ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{a^2}{w^2}+(\frac{p_{0_y}-y}{y-v})^2=\frac{b^2}{w^2}+(\frac{p_{1_y}-y}{y-v})^2$$
Can and how do I find $y$ and $w$ if all other variables are known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve in terms of $U$

$$\frac{a^2}{w^2}+(\frac{p_{0_y}-y}{y-v})^2= U;\;$$
$$\frac{b^2}{w^2}+(\frac{p_{1_y}-y}{y-v})^2=U\;$$

To solve for two variables you need two equations. You gave one.

Comment: That is really helpful, wish I had thought of it.

Comment: My solution does not seem to be right, could you help me?

Comment: $y=\frac{b^2(v^2-p_{0_y}^2)+a^2(p_{1_y}^2-v^2}{2(b^2(p_{0_y}-v)+a^2(v-p_{1_y})}$ Did you edit this? If so, how did you solve for y without involving U ? Say U=1, then we can find (y,w).

Comment: I decided my equation does not capture what I want to do. If I get the time, I might post a new question. Thank you.